# query multi namespace xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

xml:

```
<lev:Locatie axisLabels="x y" srsDimension="2" srsName="epsg:28992" uomLabels="m m">
    <gml:exterior xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <gml:LinearRing>
            <gml:posList>
            222518.0 585787.0 222837.0 585875.0 223229.0 585969.0 223949.0 586123.0 223389.0 586579.0 223305.0 586564.0 222690.0 586464.0 222706.0 586319.0 222424.0 586272.0 222287.0 586313.0 222054.0 586517.0 221988.0 586446.0 222174.0 586305.0 222164.0 586292.0 222172.0 586202.0 222232.0 586143.0 222279.0 586149.0 222358.0 586076.0 222422.0 586018.0 222518.0 585787.0
            </gml:posList>
        </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:exterior>
</lev:Locatie>
```

I need to get to the gml:posList. I tried the following

SimpleXML:

```
$xmldata     = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xmlns       = $xmldata->getNamespaces(true);

$retval = array();

foreach( $xmldata as $attr => $child ) {
    if ( (string)$child !== '' ) {
        $retval[$attr] = (string)$child;
    }
    else {
        $retval[$attr] = $child->children( $xmlns['gml'] );
    }
}
var_export( $retval );
```

xpath:

```
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadXML($xml );
$xpath = new DOMXpath($domdoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('l', $xmlns['lev'] );
$xpath->registerNamespace('g', $xmlns['gml'] );
var_export( $xml->xpath('//g:posList') );
```

If I query the attributes for lev:Locatie, I can get them, however, I seem unable to retrieve the gml:posList's value or the attributes for e.g gml:exterior. I know I'm doing something wrong, I just don't see what ...

Answer (score 1):

You're registering the namespaces on the DOMXpath instance, but use a `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` call. That will not work. You can register them on the `SimpleXMLElement` using `SimpleXMLElement::registerXpathNamespace()` or you switch to DOM and use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. The attributes do not have a prefix, so they are not in a namespace. `gml:exterior` does not have any attributes, only the namespace definition. It looks like an attribute but it is handled differently by the parser.

The nice thing about `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is that it can a node list or a scalar depending on the Xpath expression. So you can fetch a value directly.

For example the `gml:posList`:

```
$xmlString = <<<'XML'
<lev:Locatie axisLabels="x y" srsDimension="2" srsName="epsg:28992" uomLabels="m m" xmlns:lev="urn:lev">
    <gml:exterior xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
        <gml:LinearRing>
            <gml:posList>
            222518.0 585787.0 222837.0 
            </gml:posList>
        </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:exterior>
</lev:Locatie>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('g', 'http://www.opengis.net/gml');
var_export( 
  $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(//g:posList)') 
);
```

Output:

```
'222518.0 585787.0 222837.0'
```

`normalize-space()` is an Xpath function that replaces all sequences of whitespaces with a single space and trims the result. Because it is a string function it triggers a implicit cast of the first node from the location path.

Comment: Thanks  a heap Thomas, I'll be trying that out